# Url.Action within @helper does not raise event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having issues with an Action link within the @helper.
See below this line

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Category", new { id = item.Id })">
```

It simply does not raise event. What am i doing wrong here?

```
@helper ShowTree(IEnumerable<FrontEnd.Controllers.SharedController.Category> categories)
            { 
                    <ul id="@(Added == false ? "categories" : "")" class="parent-1">
                        @foreach (FrontEnd.Controllers.SharedController.Category item in categories)
                        {
                            Added = true;
                            <li class="child-1 has-sublist">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Category", new { id = item.Id })">
                                    @item.CategoryName

                                    @if (item.Children.Count > 0)
                                    {  <span>
                                        [@item.Children.Count]
                                    </span>
                                    }

                                </a>

                            @if (item.Children.Any())
                            {
                                    @ShowTree(item.Children)
                            }
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
            }
```

Comment: what "Event" are you referring to? To go to a different URL specified in your Action method?

Comment: does your controller get hit? Do you get any errors or exceptions? The controller I am referring to is the "Listing" controller (as specified in your Url.Action)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Yes, exactly, i meant the post to the controller. e.preventDefault(); of included javascript was blocking the request.

Comment: I see. you didn't post the whole relevant code :)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I am sorry someone else has already written the javascript before me within this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Just found the cure.

Javascript was blocking the request to the controller..

```
$('#categories > li a').click(function(e){
            if($(this).parent().hasClass('has-sublist')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }....
.................
```

Comment: There is nothing in your question indicating any javascript! Delete the question - its of not use to anyone

Comment: @StephenMuecke If i knew that javascript was blocking this, i would not ask. Anyway how can i delete this?

Comment: Click the delete link at the bottom of the question :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just did, but it said it contains answers. I just flagged it for closing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the following??

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.CategoryName, "Index", "Listing", new { id = item.Id }, null, null)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I think you mean `@Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: There is no difference between this and the verbose way OP has done it.